# ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs. Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras-layer, tf.keras

I am currently trying to use the first 50 layers of the MobileNetV2. Therefore, I want to extract those layers and create a new model.

I thought I could just call every layer, but the "block_2_add" layer causes an error and I don't understand why.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model

mobile_net=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224,224,3), alpha=0.5, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')


inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x=mobile_net.layers[1](inputs)
for layer in mobile_net.layers[2:50]:
  x=layer(x)




{'name': 'block_2_add', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-5873b9344fa3> in <module>()
      3 for layer in mobile_net.layers[2:50]:
      4   print(layer.get_config())
----> 5   x=layer(x)
      6 
      7 for layer in mobile_net.layers[:50]:

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in call(self, inputs)
    119   def call(self, inputs):
    120     if not isinstance(inputs, list):
--> 121       raise ValueError('A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.')
    122     if self._reshape_required:
    123       reshaped_inputs = []

ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the MobileNetV2 is not a sequential model, i.e. the layers graph is not linear. If you want just the output of the model and not any intermediate layer outputs, I think following code should do the job (even though it seems that you want to compute the last layer before output, the result still should be what you want):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model

mobile_net=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224,224,3), alpha=0.5, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')


inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
output = mobile_net(inputs)
```

Comment: Yes, its not a sequential model, see: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet_v2.py#L480

Comment: That's true, but due to the fact that my new dataset is quite small I just need the last layers of the neural network. Do you know a way how I can extract these?

Comment: I think you are already extracting it by setting `include_top=False`, if you call `mobile_net(inputs)` you are probably getting the output of the last layer because of the flag. Check the shape of my code if it matches the original network output or of the last layer, that should tell you which layer you are getting.

Comment: What I meant by that Is I only want the first, let's s say 50 layers of mobilenet. I want to discard the fully connected layers as well as some layers before those. How can I do that?

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but I am wondering if you got an answer or not? Since I want to do the same thing and currently is facing the same problem.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, I did not. I just gave up :(

Answer (score 3):

I may be late but I guess this following code will do it for you

```
pre_trained_model = MobileNetV2(input_shape = (256, 256, 3), 
                            include_top = False, 
                            weights = "imagenet" )
last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('block_15_project_BN'#the name of the last layer you want from the model)
last_output = last_layer.output
input_l = pre_trained_model.input
base_model1 = tf.keras.Model(input_l, last_output
                         )
```